# iOS App file size in ad-hoc distribution is still large compared to before optimization

Tags: ios

I created my game on iOS. Firstly, I only use pure .pvr asset and the overall "Estimated App Store Size" is ~60 MB. Then I switched to use .pvr.ccz as I checked it can reduce file size for each individual image asset for half or more. The result of this switching is that I still get "Estimated App Store Size" equals to ~60 MB, really not I expect.

I also checked .ipa file generated for the case of .pvr.ccz version, it's still around ~60 MB.

I came across to read [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/why-is-our-app-twice-as-large-as-what-we-submitted-contagious-zeros/) in which it stated in quote as

> "When your application is delivered to Apple, it is encrypted for DRM purposes and re-compressed. When the encryption is added, the size of the compressed file will increase. The exact size of the increase will vary from app to app, however, the size increase can be large when the binary has a lot of contagious zeros in it. We are unable to guarantee the size of your file after the encryption has been added."

So this might mean I have no hope for it to get reducing in file size even whenever I submit to Apple Store for release, the size will get larger.

What am I missing? or something is wrong? How can I reduce the overall file size?

Comment: What is `.pvr` and `.pvr.ccz`?

Comment: It's the format of texture being used in the game on iOS for better or maximum performance. It's friendly with iOS. For .ccz, it's compression.

Comment: AFAIK only the binary will be encrypted, so your `.pvr` assets shouldn't be affected. On the other hand, Apple might compress your app bundle and compressing `.ccz` files again might yield no benefit. So it wouldn't help to compress your `.pvr` files as Apple will do so before distributing your app anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MrMage, I would love to believe that as well. But it would be total risky to rely only on Apple side. For this rate, if I don't do any compression I will reach 100 or 200 MB pretty soon. .ccz should benefit in reducing it in some ways. I saw it can reduce in individual file size, but not overall at the end, there must be something going on there.

Comment: `.ipa` files also are zipped already, so again: it doesn't matter if the compression is applied beforehand (by converting files to `.ccz`) or when zipping for the IPA file. Also, how large is your executable file?